# OSGi SOAP web service client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, osgi, apache-karaf

I am trying to get a web service client working from OSGi, I am using Felix as my container.

So far I have tried using Apache CXF.  This would not work with my web service as it is RPC/encoded and not supported when I try to generate stubs.  I used apache Axis to generate my stubs and now I am running into issues w/ dependencies in my bundles.  As my bundles are deployed I get dependencies w/ dependencies of the the apache bundles.

I have am using maven for my builds and have used the maven-bundle-plugin with a bundleall goal to get the dependency bundles, but still run into issues with the bundle dependencies.  I would really like to use osgi, as the pluggable nature through bundles is exactly what I need, however I am spending a lot of time chasing down bundle dependencies.

Are there any clear cut examples of consuming a SOAP web service from OSGi, including how to resolve the dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your life easier, you might want to try using fuse esb (apache servicemix) or karaf. Felix is a bare minimum OSGi container whereas Karaf is Felix with many of the most important bundles already deployed. Fuse (also called servicemix) is karaf with even more bundles. Fuse comes with cxf so you don't have to mess with it.

If you'd really prefer to use felix, please post your maven bundle plugin configuration as well as a list of your bundles running in felix. I've been using CXF in Felix/Karaf to serve JAX-RS webservices for quite a while and it's a pretty powerful solution.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have tried many things and remembered that I actually had to use axis to generate my stubs as the wsdls I am using are RPC/encoded.  So I get issues resolving bundles around apache.  The current bundle I am trying to resolve is package org.apache.axiom.om

Comment: ok, I have moved to karaf, and things are working a little better.  I can actually install my bundle.  However when I actually try to invoke the webservice call in my bundle activator to test, I get noClassDefFoundError.  Below is the stacktrace, however is there a way to look at how the classpath is loading for a bundle?  Or what is the best way to track this down?  I have that class available in a bundle, however it is not getting loaded correctly.

Comment: Stacktrace


java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/stream/util/StreamReaderDelegate
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate not found by org.apache.ws.commons.axiom.axiom-api [138]
 at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:787)

Comment: In the Karaf console, you can use the command `headers <bundle ID>` to see what the manifest says that the bundle should import and it's display in red if OSGi can't find that package. How are you generating your list of packages to import? Are you specifying it manually in the maven-bundle-plugin or are you letting BND handle it? Generally NoClassDef issues are because you (or BND) didn't specify the class in your manifest. The headers command should give you an idea of what is going on.

Comment: I checked the headers for my bundle and the axiom-api bundle that is throwing the error.  Both of them show they are resolving all dependencies.  And there is a bundle installed that had the dependency, but it seems there is some error in the classpaths somewhere with the resolution.  Any other thoughts on how to track this down?

Comment: I got this working, what I ended up doing was wrapping the original webservices based on axis 1.x, which I could never get to work in an osgi env. and exposed an axis 2.x via java-ws(CXF). Everything is working great now.

Answer (score 0):

The bundleall goal for the maven-bundle-plugin will generate bundles for all of your dependencies.  However, it will not show you the order you have to install them for the dependencies to resolve.  One OSGi implementation that does a great job handling dependencies is the [Virgo Web Server from the Eclipse Foundation](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/).  With Virgo, you can simply copy all of the bundles generated by bundleall goal directly into the repository/usr folder, put your service into the pickup folder, and the runtime will handle the dependency resolution for you.  I have used this process with success in the past.

On a related note, unless you have a few uncommon dependencies, you should look into adding dependencies from the [SrpingSource Enterprise Bundle Repository](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/).